# Generating unique combinations for n objects of group size m without repetitions or remainders?

Tags: python, combinatorics

**EDITS**

- Added clarification on the expected output 1/5/2024
- Added further clarification on the expected output 1/11/2024
- Added final updated code at the bottom of this post. This is my initial attempt at pruning the results as Dillon Davis answer suggests. While the answer doesn't conclusively solve the problem, it's clear that more research needs to be done on my part with Stiener Systems. For that reason, I've accepted Dillon Davis's solution. 1/16/2024
- For those that are curious, [here is a database](https://ljcr.dmgordon.org/cover/table.html) containing solved Stiener systems 1/17/2024

**QUESTION**

I am trying to create an algorithm that generates all unique combinations of *m* objects of group size *n* without repetitions or remainders. The output for this algorithm should result in every object being paired with every other object exactly once.

A repetition is whenever at least two or more numbers have already been grouped together previously.
For example, `[1, 2, 3]` and `[1, 2, 4]` has a repetition of the pair `[1, 2]`.

Without remainders means that all groups of size *n* must be the same size.

The number of possible combinations for *m* and *n* can be calculated by using the function below. Additionally, because of the constraints of the problem, not all values of *m* and *n* are possible.

```
def iterations(m,n):
    num = (m**2) - m
    den = (n**2) - n
    if den <= 0 or num <= 0:
        return False
    if (m - 1) % (n - 1) != 0:
        return False
    if num % den != 0:
        return False
    return int(num/den)
```

For example, `iterations(9,3)` would return `12`. `iterations(6,3)` would return `False`. Why? Because there is no way for 6 objects (*m*) to be paired together only once using groups of 3 (*n*).

We can show this by attempting to manually construct the combinations for `m=6`, `n=3`.

```
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 4, 5]
[1, 6, _]
```

If we use the values of `m=9`, `n=3` to generate our combinations, then the expected output would be 12 different groups:

```
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 4, 5]
[1, 6, 7]
[1, 8, 9]
[2, 4, 9]
[2, 5, 7]
[2, 6, 8]
[3, 4, 6]
[3, 7, 9]
[3, 5, 8]
[4, 7, 8]
[5, 6, 9]
```

The issue I'm having is with implementing the algorithm to generate the unique combinations. This is the code block I have in place for generating the unique combinations:

```
import random

class id ():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.comparisons = []

    def update_comparisons(self, id_list):
        for id in id_list:
            if id in self.comparisons:
                self.comparisons.remove(id)
        self.comparisons.extend(id_list)
        self.comparisons.sort()
        if self.name in self.comparisons:
            self.comparisons.remove(self.name)
        return self.comparisons

def get_ids(n):
    ids = []
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        ids.append(id(i))
    return ids

# Setting the values for m and n
m = 9
n = 3

# Creating list of ids
ids_master = get_ids(m)
ids = ids_master.copy()

comparisons = []
comparison_names = []

# Getting the number of required combinations
iter = iterations(9,3)

#
for i in range(iter):
    temp = []
    pos = 0
    while len(temp) < n:

        # Selecting an id
        id_a = ids[pos]

        """
        Checking if the id within temp have already been compared 
        or is a duplicate. If yes, add to the counter.
        """
        counter = 0
        for id_b in temp:
            if id_b.name in id_a.comparisons or id_b.name == id_a.name:
                counter += 1
        """
        Checking if id_a has been compared to all other ids.
        If yes, add to the counter.
        """
        if len(id_a.comparisons) == m - 1:
            counter += 1
        """
        If id_a has passed the checks, the counter should be 0.
        If the counter is 0, append it to temp_list
        """
        if counter == 0:
            temp.append(id_a)

        pos += 1

    """
    Once we've exited the while loop,
    append the temp list to the list of comparisons.
    """
    comparisons.append(temp)

    # Updating the comparison for each id object
    for comparison in comparisons:
        names = [x.name for x in comparison]
        names.sort()

    for id in comparison:
        id.update_comparisons(names)
    comparison_names.append(names)

print(comparison_names)
```

The above code works for values of `(3, 2)`, `(5, 2)`, and `(7, 3)`. However, `(9, 3)` comes with complications. The code will generate the following comparisons before running into a roadblock:

```
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 4, 5]
[1, 6, 7]
[1, 8, 9]
[2, 4, 6]
[2, 5, 7]
```

In this case, the next combination would be `[2, 8, 9]`. This doesn't work though since the pair `[8, 9]` has already been compared in `[1, 8, 9]`. The code then keeps iterating through the positions until it runs out of items to check in the list and gives the error "list index out of range".

I need a way for the algorithm to anticipate these errors. For example, the if the code generated `[2, 4, 9]` first instead of `[2, 4, 6]`, the remaining combinations would *probably* work themselves out as normal. I'm sure there is a way to implement this but I'm not sure how to proceed.

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATED CODE**

First, I've updated the `update_comparisons(self, id_list, mode = 'add')` method for the id class as well as renamed the `iterations(m,n)` function to `valid_comobos(m,n)` for clarity.

```
import random

class id ():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.comparisons = []

    def update_comparisons(self, id_list, mode = 'add'):
        # Removing duplicates
        for id in id_list:
            if id in self.comparisons:
                self.comparisons.remove(id)
        if mode == 'add':  
            self.comparisons.extend(id_list)
            self.comparisons.sort()
            if self.name in self.comparisons:
                self.comparisons.remove(self.name)
            return self.comparisons
        if mode == 'del':
            for id in id_list:
                if id in self.comparisons:
                    self.comparisons.remove(id)
            self.comparisons.sort()
            return self.comparisons
        if mode == 'reset':
            self.comparisons.clear()
            return self.comparisons
```

Secondly, I've added `try:` and `except:` statements to prune invalid results.

```
# Setting the values for m and n
m = 9
n = 3

# Creating list of ids
ids_master = get_ids(m)
ids = ids_master.copy()

comparisons = []
comparison_names = []
invalid = []
invalid_names = []

# Getting the number of required combinations
combos = valid_combos(m,n)

while len(comparisons) < combos:
    temp = []
    pos = 0
    while len(temp) < n:
        try:
            if len(comparisons) < (m - 1)/(n - 1):
                if len(temp) == 0:
                    temp.append(ids[0])
                else:
                    id_a = random.choice(ids[1:])
                    counter = 0
                    
                    for id_b in temp:
                        if id_b.name in id_a.comparisons or id_b.name == id_a.name:
                            counter += 1
                       
                    if counter == 0:
                        temp.append(id_a)
            else:  
                id_a = ids[pos]
                """
                Checking if the id within temp have already been compared 
                or is a duplicate. If yes, add to the counter.
                """
                counter = 0
                for id_b in temp:
                    if id_b.name in id_a.comparisons or id_b.name == id_a.name:
                        counter += 1
        
                """
                Checking if id_a has been compared to all other ids.
                If yes, add to the counter.
                """
                if len(id_a.comparisons) == m - 1:
                    counter += 1
                """
                If the counter is 0 after the first two checks, validate it.
                If the the validation check fails, add to the counter.
                If the validation check succeeds, the counter will equal 0.
                If the counter is 0, append the id to the temp_list
                """
                if counter == 0:
                    v_check = temp.copy()
                    v_check.append(id_a)
                    v_names = [x.name for x in v_check]
                    for iv in invalid:
                        iv_names = [x.name for x in iv]
                        if v_names == iv_names:
                            counter += 1
                
                if counter == 0:
                    temp.append(id_a)
    
                pos += 1
            
        except Exception as e:
            temp.clear()
            counter = 0
            group_counter = 0
            for comparison in comparisons:
                id = comparison[0]
                if len(id.comparisons) != m - 1:
                    if counter == 0:
                        invalid.append(comparison)
                    counter += 1
            
            if counter == 0:
                group_id = comparisons[-1][0]
                previous_group_id = group_id.name - 1
                for comparison in comparisons:
                    if comparison[0].name == group_id.name:
                        group_counter += 1
                    if comparison[0].name == previous_group_id:
                        if counter == 0:
                            invalid.append(comparison)
                        counter += 1

            for i in range(counter + group_counter):
                comparisons.remove(comparisons[-1])
                
            for id in ids:
                id.update_comparisons([], mode = 'reset')
            for comparison in comparisons:
                names = [x.name for x in comparison]
                comparison_names.append(names)
                for id in comparison:
                    id.update_comparisons(names, mode = 'add')
            for iv in invalid:
                iv_names = [x.name for x in iv]
            break
    
    if len(temp) == n:
        comparisons.append(temp)
    
    comparison_names = []
    # Updating the comparison for each id object
    for comparison in comparisons:
        names = [x.name for x in comparison]
        comparison_names.append(names)
        for id in comparison:
            id.update_comparisons(names, mode = 'add')
```

Some outputs for different values of *m* and *n*.

```
m = 7
n = 3

[[1, 2, 5], 
[1, 7, 4], 
[1, 3, 6], 
[2, 3, 4], 
[2, 6, 7], 
[3, 5, 7], 
[4, 5, 6]]
```

```
m = 9
n = 3

[[1, 8, 4], 
[1, 3, 2], 
[1, 9, 6], 
[1, 7, 5], 
[2, 4, 7], 
[2, 5, 6], 
[2, 8, 9], 
[3, 4, 6], 
[3, 5, 8], 
[3, 7, 9], 
[4, 5, 9], 
[6, 7, 8]]
```

```
m = 13
n = 4

[[1, 11, 6, 13], 
[1, 5, 8, 12], 
[1, 3, 10, 9], 
[1, 4, 7, 2], 
[2, 3, 5, 11], 
[2, 6, 8, 9], 
[2, 10, 12, 13], 
[3, 4, 6, 12], 
[3, 7, 8, 13], 
[4, 5, 9, 13], 
[4, 8, 10, 11], 
[5, 6, 7, 10], 
[7, 9, 11, 12]]
```

While this does provide results for some combinations of *m* and *n*, it still does not generalize for all possible combinations of *m* and *n*. However, as Dillon Davis has said, there is no known generalized solution yet.

Comment: have you looked at the functions in `itertools` to see if any meet your needs? Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: itertools works for smaller values of m and n. However, when larger values are considered, the exponential nature the combinations function of makes the code very inefficient.

Comment: The "iter" in `itertools` stands for iterators. This makes generating combinations quite efficient at any input size.

Comment: Is there a way to efficiently pull the results for large sets of combinations? If we consider a list of 96 objects and we group them into sets of 6 that would create 927,048,304 different combinations.  This only gets worse for larger values. I am not aware of a way to filter these as they are created.

Comment: Yes, well, at least *more* efficiently than my original answer. See my updated answer.

Comment: One more try with some pruning in the `combinations` function filtered the 927,048,304 combinations in ~30s.

Comment: I realized there's a fundamental issue in the problem description in that there can be multiple correct answers that are not always the same size. For example (m=6,n=3) could be `(0,1,2),(3,4,5)` or `(0,1,2),(0,3,4),(1,3,5),(2,4,5)`. The first set fulfills all required conditions and includes *all* combinations as no other combination can be added. If your problem is actually to find the set of valid combinations with maximum size then it's back to the drawing board.

Comment: I added some clarification to the problem statement to explain why (m=6, n=3) is not a valid output.

Comment: *The output for this algorithm should result in every object being paired with every other object exactly once.* The addition of this restriction pretty much invalidates all of my suggested approaches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is exactly that  of the construction of [Steiner Systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steiner_system#CITEREFCarmichael1931). Unfortunately, there is not a general algorithm for constructing `S(2, k, n)` for arbitrary `k` and `n`.  For `k=3`, the problem has been extensively studied as "Steiner Triple Systems" (STS) and `k=4` "Steiner Quadruple Systems" (SQS).

Other than those two fixed `k`, there's also an approach based in projective geometry that produces a steiner system for `k=p^q` and `n=k^2+k+1`, where `p` is prime. However, this approach is extremely limited.

I also perused the literature for heuristics on constructing steiner systems, but found surprisingly little. Seems that people really just use a tree search with decent pruning rules.

I will also point out that your calculation for the number of groups is correct when a solution exists, but don't not exclude all systems without solutions. The two major rules for admissibility of steiner systems are as follows:

1. If there exists an `S(t, k, v)` then there exists an `S(t-1, k-1, v-1)`
2. If there exists an `S(t, k, v)` then `C(k, t)` divides `C(v, t)`

Where `S(t, k, v)` denotes a steiner system of `v` base elements in groups of `k` elements where each subset of `t` elements occurs in exact one group, and `C(n, m)` is "n choose m".

These two theorems correspond to your 2nd and 3rd conditionals, but these conditions are not sufficient- even if your values satisfy these constraints, there may not be a valid solution to the system. I'm not aware of a better test, but you should still be aware that a solution simply may not exist despite passing these tests.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't quite follow the logic in your code to see what you're doing wrong but I came up with this that seems to satisfy your requirements:

```py
import itertools  # for itertools.combinations
import functools  # for functools.reduce

n=3
m=9

# track a list of valid combinations; a valid combination has
# elements that don't have more than 1 value in common with other
# valid combinations
valid = []

# loop through every possible combination given (m, n)
for combo in itertools.combinations(range(m), n):
    # check each possible combination against every valid combination
    for v in valid:
        if len(v & set(combo)) > 1:
            break  # this combo has more than 1 element in common
    else:
        valid.append(set(combo))

# (m,n) is valid if all members of m are represented in the list of
# valid combinations
if len(functools.reduce(set.union, valid)) == m:
    print(f'({m}, {n}) is valid and produces {len(valid)} combinations')
    print(valid)
```

```
(9, 3) is valid and produces 8 combinations
[{0, 1, 2}, {0, 3, 4}, {0, 5, 6}, {0, 8, 7}, {1, 3, 5}, {1, 4, 6}, {2, 3, 6}, {2, 4, 5}]
```

---

**Edit**: Based on your comment to efficiently generate large number of valid combinations, here is an alternative implementation. This version stores a small amount of state and outputs valid combinations on request. It'll still take forever to produce all the values of m,n = 96,6 but each individual combination can be acted up without having to calculate them all.

```py
import itertools

def valid_combos(m, n):
    seen_pairs = set()  # this will only grow to C(m,2) elements

    # loop through every possible combination given (m, n)
    for combo in itertools.combinations(range(m), n):
        combo_pairs = set()
        for pair in itertools.combinations(combo, 2):
            if pair in seen_pairs:
                break
            combo_pairs.add(pair)
        else:
            seen_pairs |= combo_pairs
            yield combo

for count, combo in enumerate(valid_combos(96, 5), start=1):
    print(combo)
print(f'{count=}')
```

Some optimization could be made by using multithreading or async in the generator. Further optimization may be found by implementing a custom version of `itertools.combinations` where the check for `seen_pairs` can be integrated into the logic, short circuiting the generation of invalid combinations.

---

**Last Edit**: I tried a modified reference implementation of `itertools.combinations` to prune chunks off of the input space. Timing results for `m,n=96,6` at the bottom.

```py
import itertools

def pruned_combinations(n, r, seen_pairs):
    """modified itertools.combinations reference implementation:
       https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations
    """
    if r > n:
        return
    indices = list(range(r))
    yield tuple(indices)
    while True:
        for i in reversed(range(r)):
            if indices[i] != i + n - r:
                break
        else:
            return

        indices[i] += 1
        for j in range(i+1, r):
            indices[j] = indices[j-1] + 1

        # prune, if possible
        for z in range(1, r-2):
            if tuple(indices[z-1:z+1]) in seen_pairs:
                if indices[z] != z+n-r:
                    indices[z] += 1
                    for j in range(z+1, r):
                        indices[j] = indices[j-1] + 1
                break
        else:
            yield tuple(indices)

def valid_combos(m, n):
    seen_pairs = set()  # this will only grow to C(m,2) elements

    for combo in pruned_combinations(m, n, seen_pairs):
        combo_pairs = set(itertools.combinations(combo, 2))
        for pair in combo_pairs:
            if pair in seen_pairs:
                break
        else:
            seen_pairs |= combo_pairs
            yield combo


import timeit
start_time = timeit.default_timer()
for count, combo in enumerate(valid_combos(96, 6), start=1):
    pass
print(f'{count=}')
print(f'time: {timeit.default_timer()-start_time:.2f} seconds')
```

```
count=211
time: 32.66 seconds
```

Comment: Thanks, this is very informative! I just have one thing I would appreciate some clarification on. How do the pairs get added to the seen_pairs variable? I see that it's initiated as an empty set, but then it appears to be immediately accessed for information even though it hasn't gotten anything inside yet? Please forgive me if this seems like a silly question.

Comment: If the combination is valid then the set of pairs in that combination is added to `seen_pairs` in the line `seen_pairs |= combo_pairs`. The `|=` operator is shorthand for assigning the result of `set.union`. The line is equivalent to: `seen_pairs = seen_pairs.union(combo_pairs)`